# Column for SharePoint list which gives a current numeric date value that updates each day

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, calculated-column-formula, json-formatting, column-formatting

I was told that you can't do this with a Calculated Column (is this true?  sounds bizarre!).

The closest I've found is a JSON column format (below) which sets an integer value.

However I can't manipulate that value with a calculation from another column.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=floor((Number(@now)-Number([$Created]))/(1000*60*60*24))"
}
```

Comment: `I can't manipulate that value with a calculation from another column`, what do you mean by this? Are you trying to use another list column in JSON calculation above or something else?

Comment: [Column1] has the JSON code above and generates an integer which increments daily, currently evaluates to 18937.   If I Set [Column2] as a calculated field = [Column1]  I'm getting zero

Comment: How [Column 1] increments daily? Are you updating it manually or using script / workflow?

Comment: From the JSON field Now function  ...
txtContent": "=floor((Number(@now)-Number([$Created]))/(1000*60*60*24))

Comment: This is the expected behavior as JSON Formatting only shows the values in list views, it does not actually store the values in [Column 1]. So, you cannot get these value in calculated columns using [Column 1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[$FieldName]` to reference the values of other columns within the same row by specifying the **internal name** of the column surrounded by square brackets and preceded by a dollar sign like: `[$InternalName]`.

So, in JSON, you need to use the **internal name** of your `Column1` column in your JSON code like:

```
[$Column1]
```

Check below URL to find out the internal name of SharePoint column:

[Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

**Reference**:

1. [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.  I have the new Column [DateCount] working with JSON "txtContent": "= Number([$StartDate]) - floor((Number(@now)-Number([$Created]))/(1000*60*60*24)) - 25568".  

However when I filter the list based on this column I'm getting no results.   "Show items when the following is true  DateCount is greater than or equal to 1"

Comment: The JSON column formatting does not change the data in the columns; it only changes how it’s displayed to users who browse the list. So, you cannot filter / sort based on JSON formatted columns assuming the results will be based on what you see in list view.

Comment: So I'm back to square one.   I'm trying to create a list where I am only displaying rows for which the date column is >= Today filtering out all rows for which the date has passed.  How do I go about that?

Comment: Apply filters on list view based on `[Today] `. Check this [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4)

Comment: thank you!!!  easy as that - wow.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint calculated columns are calculated when the item is saved. The calculated column is not constantly evaluated and updated when it contains a volatile reference like [Today].  That is what you need to understand about SharePoint.

Using JSON, you can reference the values of any other data column, so why not perform the calculation in JSON from scratch? That way you don't need to rely on items having to be saved.

Another option might be to access the SharePoint data from a reporting tool. Excel or Power BI come to mind. These tools are built for that kind of thing and it will be easy to achieve.

Comment: I've tried that but can't seem to access the other columns within the JSON field.  How do I access an integer value from another Column in the JSON????

Answer (score 0):

This is normal phenomenon. Because the JSON format only displays the values in the list view, it does not actually store the values in [Column1]. Therefore [Cloumn2] gets a null value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response